# Coredata - updating information

Tags: swift, core-data, swift3, xcode8

I have two viewcontrollers.
VC1 is home viewcontroller.
In VC2 I have text fields so that the user inputs results and a save button where data is saved.
The strange thing is when I save I have a fetchrequest to show new data but... whats happening is that old data being showed to me.

But if I go to VC1, new data is there.

This is my code (VC2):

```
@IBOutlet var designLabel: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var localLabel: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var typeLabel: UITextField!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<Arm> = Land.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = %@",  "\(choosenArmID!)")

    do{
        let searchResults = try DatabaseController.getContext().fetch(fetchRequest)

        for result in searchResults as [Arm]{
               //to get results in coredata and put them in the text fields: for edition
                self.title = result.designation
                designLabel.text = result.designation
                localLabel.text = result.local
                typeLabel.text = result.type
        }
    }
    catch{
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }

}
```

for the save button I have this:

```
@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    let app = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = app.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Arm")
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = %@",  "\(choosenArmID!)")        
    do {
        let results = try context.fetch(request)

        if results.count > 0 {

            for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {

                    result.setValue(designLabel.text, forKey: "designation")
                    result.setValue(typeLabel.text, forKey: "type")
                    result.setValue(localLabel.text, forKey: "local")

                do {
                    try context.save()
                    print("context saved") //I get into this
                } catch {
                    print("Error updating")
                }   
            }
        }
    } catch {

        print ("Error")
    }


 //I do another fetchrequest to show new results

    let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<Arm> = Arm.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = %@",  "\(choosenArmID!)")

    do{
        let searchResults = try DatabaseController.getContext().fetch(fetchRequest)

        for result in searchResults as [Arm]{
            print("New saved Results: ")
            print("title: \(result.designation!)")
            print("local: \(result.local!)")
            print("type: \(result.type!)")
        }
    }
    catch{
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }

}
```

Now in the new results I'd expected the new saved results, but instead I get the old ones, even though the new results were saved!!! 
Can you help me please?

Comment: Are you sure that the data is being saved? If you search for it can you find it in the db?

Comment: Also, check to make sure your models' properties are marked with dynamic - that's tripped me up a few times.

Comment: Bolnad, When I go to vc1 data is showing ok.

Comment: Erik, where can i check if model properties are set to Dynamic?

Comment: @Erik would you be so kind to tell me how to mark those properties has dynamic? please

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke there, I meant to `@NSManaged`. You can check by opening your Arm.swift file and seeing if the variables are something like `@NSManaged public var text:String?`.

Comment: I had some problems with context but after a few hours changing code I made it. Thanks